# Load index position using a user inputted value stored in register

Tags: assembly, mips

So I have a simple program in MIPS that takes in user input for an index value for a word array that exists in memory.  So say the word is loaded as such:

```
Array: .word 0xAABBCCDD:16
```

So I take it user input and store it in $t0.  My question is how do I load that specific index from my word?  I can't think of a way to get the value of the third byte in a register.  For example, say a user would input the value 3 in the prompt

```
Input value: 3
```

Then I would want to return the value 0xAA.

```
Output: 0xAA
```

I can not think of a way to get the correct offset with the index value being in the register.  I know I cannot use two registers when using lw because there is not enough memory for it.  So, is there some simple procedure I am overlooking here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the user input value is in register `$t1`:

```
la    $t0,ARRAY   # starting address of array
addu  $t1,$t0     # add starting address to user input value
lb    $t2,($t1)   # load $t2 with the byte at (ARRAY + user_input)
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need `addu $t2, $t1, $t0`

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I guess it was just the program I was using, MARS.  I just did 
`addu $t1, $t1, $t0`

Comment: I guess it was just the program I was using, MARS.  I just did 
`addu $t1, $t1, $t0`

So now I have 0x10010003 loaded into the register, but how do I specifically print that as an integer?  The entire thing gets loaded  into $a0 when I do 
`add $a0, $t2, $zero`

So if I were to do 

`li $v0, 1`
`add $a0, $t2, $zero`
`syscall`

It prints out the value of 0xFFFFFFFF, which is -1 using MARS.